# Android 4.3 StatusBarNotification

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Is there a way to silence a specific StatusBarNotification?
I have a class that extends NotificationListenerService. I want to silence all notifications comming through my onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){}.
Thanks!

Comment: _I want to silence all notifications comming through my onNotificationPosted_ -- that sounds like a wrong assumption: notifications are posted to SystemUI (status bar) first and then your listener gets data through a service provided by SystemUI.

Comment: So when I get the statusBarNotification it's "too late" ?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without silencing all the system each time?